# How to add REST services to a RAP application

Tags: rest, web-applications, osgi, eclipse-rap

I am working on a web application which uses RAP. In the application there is one bundle which contains the model which is backed by a database. I would like to create bundles which provide REST services which will make use of the model bundle.

I looked at the `Application#addEntryPoint` but that it just for UI contributions - not for services as such.

I also read FrankAppel's post http://www.codeaffine.com/2011/08/26/raprwt-osgi-integration/ and wonder if RWT and Felix might be the way to go. It looks promising but Felix is new to me.

Is it possible to add these REST bundles to the RAP application and set them up to handle `/rest/*` URLs? Or would it be more sensible to keep the 2 parts completely separate and to share the model bundle in a different way?

Answer (score 0):

When using RAP, any active bundle may contribute to the usual   "org.eclipse.equinox.http.registry.servlets" and "org.eclipse.equinox.http.registry.resources" extension points. You just need to make sure the name of your RAP application's entry point(s) and the paths of your ressources and servlets won't overlap.

So in practice, you can just develop your REST services as if there was no RAP component. The two will happily live side-by-side within the same servlet context.